# Adding an user to www-data group not working

Tags: users, groups, html, www

I am trying to add my user to the `www-data` group in order to be able to edit the files there without admin rights. This is the command I have used to do that:

```
$ sudo usermod -aG www-data n_user

$ groups
n_user adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lxd lpadmin sambashare

$ id
uid=1000(n_user) gid=1000(n_user) groups=1000(n_user),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),111(lxd),115(lpadmin),116(sambashare)


$ grep www-data /etc/group
www-data:x:33:n_user

$ ll /var/www/html/index.html
-rw-rwSr-- 1 www-data www-data  5129 Feb 18 14:21 index.html

$ ll /var/www
total 4.0K
drwxrwSr-x 5 www-data www-data 4.0K Feb 18 13:47 html/
```

So according to me, this should be sufficient, the problem is that when I try to edit the `index.html` file, I am still getting a notification that this file is read-only and that I cannot change it without `sudo` rights.

On top of that, I don't see that my user `n_user` really belongs to the `www-data` group with GID: 33. But the `grep` command is showing me that I am a member, so I am really confused.

What am I doing wrong, and since the file and the folder this file belongs to are both writable by `www-data` group to which my user belongs, why I cannot really do any changes, without using `sudo`?

Comment: you can also use `newgrp  -  groupname` in your case `newgrp  - www-data`

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you need to logout/log back in first? You can check this by executing `groups` once again after loggin in.

Answer (score 0):

So to add the new user run

```
sudo adduser {USER-NAME-HERE} {GROUP-NAME-HERE}
sudo adduser n_user www-data
```

And then you can check with

```
groups n_user
```